# How to restore specific set of collections in MongoDb

Tags: mongodb, shell, ubuntu-16.04

I have dbs

```
UQDBclone_201806210534  0.027GB
UQDBclone_201806280424  0.080GB
UQDBclone_201807050429  0.089GB
```

I should restore specific set of collection in the 3rd one. What is the approach?

Answer (score 0):

> I should restore specific set of collection in the 3rd one. What is the approach?

Do just that, restore specific set of collections.

```
mongorestore -d UQDBclone_201807050429 -c coll_1
mongorestore -d UQDBclone_201807050429 -c coll_2
mongorestore -d UQDBclone_201807050429 -c coll_3
```

You can write a script to automate this.